# How to implement Sockets into an iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, client, client-server

First things first, I am an 18 yo student, I'm not so skilled.
I'm trying to create an iOS application, something easy just to send messages between two clients... I'm studying Java Sockets, basic level, but I found so difficult to implement these into an iOS project... (I'm a rookie at Swift).
I would like to ask you if someone knows how to do that and to explain it to me.
Thanks to you all for the time you spent.

Comment: look it [NSURLSessionWebSocketTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionwebsockettask?language=objc) and the sample link [Websockets in iOS 13 Using Swift and Xcode 11](https://medium.com/better-programming/websockets-in-ios-13-using-swift-and-xcode-11-18fa3000d802)

Comment: another sample tutorial [How to use the URLSessionWebSocketTask in Swift](https://appspector.com/blog/websockets-in-ios-using-urlsessionwebsockettask)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a very simple TCP socket here: https://github.com/tristanratz/ChatApp/blob/master/ClientApp/Socket.swift

If you want want you can have a look. You can connect to a host, send and subscribe to received messages.

Comment: do you know any way to send and receive images and other things through the socket ??? I need help with that...

Comment: It would work the same way... As you can see in the link there are two send methods. One for strings the other for Data. With minimal adjustment you could convert an image to an Data Object and send it.

Comment: I am creating an app in which both client snd server should work both way means even client can receive and send data according to the response it recieved.....can this `ChatApp` Socket work like that ????

Comment: Yeah it should work just fine. The thing you're describing is exactly a socket.

When you open a connection you can act on the response of the client in the server and if you want to send a message back from the client.
If you only need a request style connection you should look at "http". The client of the app above is a TCP client.

Comment: Thanks , I'll give it a try and get back to you :)